# How do I stop javascript automatically adding tags during selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please see [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u3xe8/)

Basically it's a text-highlighter that nearly works perfectly.

The issue arrises when tags such as **`<p>` or `<br>`** are within the selection.

The JavaScript seems to **automatically add tags**.

If you go to function **`filterHtmlLevels`** and add `alert(htmlStr);`,
then when you select an area of text over two paragraphs you can see it has added the **`<p>`** tags when it shouldn't.

I could use **`.replace`** but unsure how to safely keep the DOM structure.

EDIT

I have found it occurs during the function getSel() where it wraps a div around the selection. Unsure how to change this to NOT add extra tags - i.e. treat the html as a string

Comment: You can't treat it as a string, it won't solve the problem. You have terribly malformed HTML being produced when you select across paragraphs and the browser backfills... that's where the mysterious `</p>` is coming from. You're going to have to check your highlighted text to see if it will produce invalid markup and fix it as you go... or don't use any html in the selection area.

Comment: The problem in your fiddle is not with `filterHtmlLevels` (well, it has its own problems too, but it's not the root of your current issue). It's with the way you get your selections with `getSel`. The exact same breakup behaviour occurs on selection here: http://jsfiddle.net/NbRc4/

Comment: thanks guys, I managed to sort it. Feel free to use my fiddle! Any updates please let me know - share the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed (TESTED CHROME ONLY):

http://jsfiddle.net/6L58X/

Please comment with any updates / improvements, or edit!

Documented for if link dies:

JS:

```
$('#highlightable').bind('mouseup', function () {
    highlight();
});


function highlight() {
    // not IE case
    var selHtml;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        selHtml = getSel();
    }
    // IE case
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange && document.selection.type != "None") {
        selHtml = getSelIE();
    }
    else { return; }
    if(selHtml.length == 0) { return; }
    var allhtml = $('#highlightable').html().toString();
    var temphhtml = '<div class="temph">';
    var pos = allhtml.indexOf(temphhtml);
    var endpos = pos + selHtml.length;

    var preSelStr = allhtml.substring(0, pos);
    var postSelStr = allhtml.substring((pos + temphhtml.length + selHtml.length + 6), allhtml.length);

    preSelStr = cleanEnd(preSelStr);
    postSelStr = cleanStart(postSelStr);

    //alert(preSelStr+'          '+postSelStr);
    var prepend = '<span class="highlighted">';
    var postpend = '</span>';

    var cs = countSpans(preSelStr);
    if (cs > 0) {
        prepend = '';

        var insSS = locations('<span class="highlighted">', selHtml);
        var insSE = locations('</span>', selHtml);

        if (insSS.length > insSE.length) {
            postpend = postpend + '<span class="highlighted">';
        } else if (insSS.length == insSE.length) {
            postpend = '';
        }
    }
    var newSelStr = filterHtmlLevels(selHtml, allhtml);
   // alert(newSelStr);
    var newHtml = preSelStr + prepend + newSelStr + postpend + postSelStr;
    //  alert(newHtml);
    $('#highlightable').html(newHtml);

}

function cleanEnd(preSelStr) {
    var tags = ["</p>", "</ p>"];
    if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith != 'function') {
        String.prototype.endsWith = function (str) {
            return this.slice(-str.length) == str;
        };
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        if (preSelStr.endsWith(tags[i])) {
            var len = tags[i].length;
            var cleanStr = preSelStr.substring(0, preSelStr.length - len);
            return cleanStr;
        }
    }
    return preSelStr;
}

function cleanStart(postSelStr) {
    if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
        String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
            return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
        };
    }
    var tags = ["<p>", "<br />", "<br/>"];
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        if (postSelStr.startsWith(tags[i])) {
            var len = tags[i].length;
            var cleanStr = postSelStr.substring(len, postSelStr.length);
            return cleanStr;
        }
    }
    return postSelStr;
}

function filterHtmlLevels(htmlStr, allhtml) {
    var newStr = htmlStr.replace(/<span class="highlighted">/g, "");
    newStr = newStr.replace(/<\/span>/g, '');
    newStr = cleanEnd(newStr);
    newStr = cleanStart(newStr);
   // alert(htmlStr);
     newStr = newStr.replace(/<p>/g, '</span><p><span class="highlighted">');
      newStr = newStr.replace(/<\/p>/g, '</span></p><span class="highlighted">');
    return newStr;
}

function locations(substring, string) {
    var a = [],
        i = -1;
    while ((i = string.indexOf(substring, i + 1)) >= 0) a.push(i);
    return a;
}

function getSel() {
    var selObj = window.getSelection();
    var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
    var newElement = document.createElement("b");
    var documentFragment = selRange.extractContents();
    newElement.appendChild(documentFragment);
    var filteredElement = divWrap(newElement.innerHTML);
    selRange.insertNode(filteredElement);
    selObj.removeAllRanges();
    return filteredElement.innerHTML.toString();
}

function getSelIE() {
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    var selectedText = range.htmlText;
    var newText = '<div class="temph">' + selectedText + '</div>';
    document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(newText);
    return newText;
}

function divWrap(htmlString) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.className = "temph";
    wrapper.innerHTML = htmlString;
    return wrapper;
}

function countSpans(preSelStr) {
    // returns 0 if same num, > 0 if more span starts
    var StartSpans = locations(preSelStr, '<span class="highlighted">');
    var EndSpans = locations(preSelStr, '</span>');
    var count = StartSpans.length - EndSpans.length;
    return count;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="highlightable">
    <p id="p1">stibulum nisl orci, viverra in sollicitudin sed, iaculis vel erat. Nam lacus quam, volutpat et porta non, consequat ac tortor. Fusce non lorem vitae</p>
    <p>libero imperdiet convallis. Morbi vestibulum viverra ligula, porttitor dapibus justo dictum ut. Pellentesque eget laoreet metus. Curabitur rhoncus consectetur nulla, id imperdiet nulla pellentesque sit amet. Cras sodales arcu ac orci suscipit pulvinar sollicitudin risus gravida. Praesent condimentum erat sit amet ipsum tristique mattis. Cras dolor ante, hendrerit vel suscipit a, pellentesque sit amet felis. Vivamus suscipit, tellus ut sollicitudin pulvinar, odio urna auctor quam, ut bibendum ipsum arcu ac nibh. Phasellus sollicitudin, ipsum at pretium consectetur, arcu nisi auctor quam, a lobortis erat neque viverra diam. Nam congue libero sed est gravida dignissim. Nulla pulvinar condimentum diam in porta. Aenean id interdum odio. Fusce cursus sagittis urna dictum scelerisque. Sed nunc massa, cursus et pharetra at, ullamcorper vel est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut accumsan commodo lorem, gravida rutrum diam venenatis eu.</p>
    <p id="p2">stibulum nisl orci, viverra in sollicitudin sed, iaculis vel erat. Nam lacus quam, volutpat et porta non, consequat ac tortor. Fusce non lorem vitae libero imperdiet convallis. Morbi vestibulum viverra ligula, porttitor dapibus justo dictum ut. Pellentesque eget laoreet metus. Curabitur rhoncus consectetur nulla, id imperdiet nulla pellentesque sit amet. Cras sodales arcu ac orci suscipit pulvinar sollicitudin risus gravida. Praesent condimentum erat sit amet ipsum tristique mattis. Cras dolor ante, hendrerit vel suscipit a, pellentesque sit amet felis. Vivamus suscipit, tellus ut sollicitudin pulvinar, odio urna auctor quam, ut bibendum ipsum arcu ac nibh. Phasellus sollicitudin, ipsum at pretium consectetur, arcu nisi auctor quam, a lobortis erat neque viverra diam. Nam congue libero sed est gravida dignissim. Nulla pulvinar condimentum diam in porta. Aenean id interdum odio. Fusce cursus sagittis urna dictum scelerisque. Sed nunc massa, cursus et pharetra at, ullamcorper vel est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut accumsan commodo lorem, gravida rutrum diam venenatis eu.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.highlighted {
    color: red;
}
```